# Como obter o retorno do multi curl (curl_multi_add_handle)?

Tags: php, libcurl

Queria saber como faço para obter o retorno via o multi curl por que pelo curl normal basta usar a função `curl_exec` para obter o resultado da pagina mas no multi curl eu não consigo obter nada nem com o `curl_exec`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, o `curl_multi` não é "compatível" com as funções do `curl_*`. Isso é, primeiro você cria o cURL normalmente (usando o `curl_init()` e o `curl_setopt()`), então adiciona este cURL o handle no `curl_multi_add_handle`.

Uma vez que você tem o `curl_multi_init`, você deve usar somente funções `curl_multi_*`.

---

Para executar:

```
curl_multi_exec()
```

Mas, ele tem um "mistério", porque a própria documentação fará o [CPU ir para 100%](http://www.adrianworlddesign.com/Knowledge-Base/php/Download-content-with-cURL/Doing-curlmultiexec-the-right-way), ou até entrar num loop infinito.

Existem duas formas de conter isso, usando:

```
$executando = 1;
while($executando > 0){
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $executando);
    curl_multi_select($mh);
}
```

Uma outra opção seria usar o `usleep`:

```
$executando = 1;
while($running > 0){
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $executando);
    usleep(10);
}
```

---

Agora como pego o retorno, uma vez que todos estão dentro do `curl_multi_exec`? Existem outras funções, em comparação:

```
CURL                                   CURL MULTI 

curl_exec()                            curl_multi_exec()
                                       curl_multi_getcontent()

curl_close()                           curl_multi_remove_handle()
                                       curl_multi_close()
```

Para obter o `curl_getinfo` pode usar diretamente o próprio `curl_getinfo($ch)`, agora se deseja obter a informação do cURL Multi, use `curl_multi_info_read($mh)` em seu lugar.

---

Em um exemplo de uso, obtendo o conteúdo de múltiplas páginas:

```
// Cria o primeiro cURL
$ch1 = curl_init('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1');
curl_setopt_array($ch1, [
    CURLOPT_SSLVERSION => CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,  // Isto é inseguro, não use isto em produção, altere para `1`.
    CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS => CURLPROTO_HTTPS,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1
]);

// Copia o primeiro cURL e muda a URL, criando um segundo cURL
$ch2 = curl_copy_handle($ch1);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.fixer.io/latest');
```

```
// Cria o cURL Multi
$mh = curl_multi_init();

// Importa os cURL criados
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch1);
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch2);

// Executa o cURL Multi
$running = 1;

while($running > 0){
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
    curl_multi_select($mh);
}

// Exibe primeiro cURL:
echo curl_multi_getcontent($ch1);

// Exibe segundo cURL:
echo curl_multi_getcontent($ch2);

// Fecha o cURL Multi:
curl_multi_close($mh);

// Fecha o cURL:
curl_close($ch1);
curl_close($ch2);
```

Isso irá retornar dois JSON, distintos, [um é de desta página](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1) e a outra [desta](http://api.fixer.io/latest).